# how can I send the array as a parameter to url using get request without afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsurlsession

I have to send the array as one of the parameter to the url using get request the url is http://13.229.45.226/api/resource/Employee/?filters=[["Employee", "company_email", "=", "susee@lektrify.club"]] . and i am using nsurl sessions for api calling.

please find the below code

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Employee",@"company_email",@"=",Emailid];


NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:0 error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);

NSString *urlstr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/api/resource/Employee/?filters=[\n%@]",jsonString];

 NSLog(@"%@",urlstr);

[apicall getDictionaryFromApiwithoutlogin:urlstr restfulType:kRestfulGet andUseContentType:NO withRequestBody:nil withheader:YES completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *result){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }];
```

this is the code written for the universal api calling in foe i am giving inputs.

```
    -(void)getDictionaryFromApiwithoutlogin:(NSString *)url restfulType:(NSInteger)restfulType andUseContentType:(BOOL)useContentType withRequestBody:(NSData*)httpBody withheader:(BOOL)header completionHandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *isSuccess))isSuccess
{

loginstatus = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loginStatus"];

    if (![APICall hasNetwork])
    {
        //  [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
        // [Util displayToastMessage:@"No internet connection"];
        return;
    }

    /* RESTFUL request function, all API request will come here */
    //url  = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
url=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"url:%@",url);

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:300.0];
    // set request variables
    if (restfulType == kRestfulGet) {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    } else if (restfulType == kRestfulPost) {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    } else if (restfulType == kRestfulPut) {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    } else {
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
    }

    if (useContentType) {
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    }
if (header) {
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"access_token"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}
    if (httpBody != nil) {
        request.HTTPBody = httpBody;
    }

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            if ([httpResponse respondsToSelector:@selector(statusCode)])
            {
                NSInteger responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
                NSLog(@"api response: %@", httpResponse);
                if (responseStatusCode == 200)
                {
                    NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL];
                    isSuccess(response);
                }else if (responseStatusCode==401)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];

                        [APICall sigininpageafteraccestokenexperise];

                    });

                }
                else if (responseStatusCode==500)
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];


                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"usernotfound" object:nil];
                    });

                }

                else{
                    [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
                    [APICall handleApiErrorCode:responseStatusCode];
                }
            }
        }else
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [customBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
                [Util handleErrorCodesForApi:(int)error.code];
            });
    }];
    [postDataTask resume];
    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];


}
```

When i try in post man array link this  [["Employee", "company_email", "=", "xxx@xxx.club"]] . it is working how to for this array and add to url and make get request.

thanks for quick response.

Comment: Can yo show me how you are using this thing in Postman? just update your question with your postman request snapshot.

Comment: @ArunKumar  i found the solution;thanks for your response

Comment: This question has been asked many times on the site, you should search before asking some question on SO.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry i did not find the answer from her i got it from my friends

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777252/ios-how-to-pass-array-to-afnetworking-as-parameters-objective-c what about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - How to pass array to AFNetworking as parameters (Objective-C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777252/ios-how-to-pass-array-to-afnetworking-as-parameters-objective-c)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my question

the  solution is you have to create an array,you have to NSJSONSerialization to data and to encoded string this solves the issue

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@"Employee",@"company_email",@"=",Emailid];

NSData *json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myArray options:0 error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:json encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);

NSString *urlstr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/api/resource/Employee/?filters=[\n%@]",jsonString];
```

please check the updated question for full answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSURLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents) class to construct URL from their constituent parts.

In your answer you are constructing queryString manually by self, it is ok with one parameter, but if you have multiple parameters then it will got hectic.

for your example:

```
    NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://13.229.45.226/api/resource/Employee/"];
    NSURLQueryItem *item1 = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"filters" value:@"Employee"];
    NSURLQueryItem *item2 = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"company_email" value:@"susee@lektrify.club"];
    [urlComponents setQueryItems: @[item1,item2]];
    NSLog(@"%@",urlComponents.URL);
```

Output:

```
http://13.229.45.226/api/resource/Employee/?filters=Employee&company_email=susee@lektrify.club
```